# select column value of a dataframe based on a row value in other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My first data frame looks like below:

```
    W   X   Y   Z   TARGET
0   1   2   3   4   A
1   3   4   5   6   C
2   2   3   4   5   B
```

Second data frame is:

```
    A   B   C   D
0   0.9 0.0 0.0 0.1
1   0.1 0.2 0.7 0.0
2   0.4 0.6 0.0 0.0
```

Based on the target value of the first dataframe I need to search the column value in second dataframe and output the following.

```
    W   X   Y   Z   TARGET  PROB
0   1   2   3   4   A       0.9    
1   3   4   5   6   C       0.7
2   2   3   4   5   B       0.6
```

I have tried different approaches and never successful. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `lookup` problem:

```
df1['PROB'] = df2.lookup(df2.index, df1.TARGET)
```

Output:

```
   W  X  Y  Z TARGET  PROB
0  1  2  3  4      A   0.9
1  3  4  5  6      C   0.7
2  2  3  4  5      B   0.6
```